Finding the next number in this sequence: 184275, 8292375, 3108105, ...,
I created this puzzle myself. Find the next number in this sequence and explain:
184275,
8292375,
3108105,
54729675,
147349125,
1587160575,
24135786675,
20906353125,
214266677625,
1676096296875,
9146402236125,
1188789606687375,
14837043862265625,
1268003106995625,
6561917002265625,
8610547490372953125,
30045013821087890625,
28918096701384515625,
928812978295467890625,
84135026523693427734375,
31040254903911427001953125,
38040322494031410287109375,
14178173111759846677863375,
392957986987929699059600830078125,
3481003119670913301423504641336001258544921875,
7400986580290704788541460659891195543870408269175363049221038818359375
Hint:

 This is an unusual group of numbers.

Hint (this might make it too easy):

 The finished sequence has length 27. What 27 unusual groups exist?


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

It might be too early for an hint. Please try to wait for 24 hours :) I think the tags are enough for a hint for now

I find that the numbers are all products of small primes.  The largest prime factor in any of them is 73 (and that's the last one).  I don't know if this is relevant.  As for the hint, perhaps rot13(hahfhny nf va bqq?) (I hope not.)

rot13 is not involved.

The next number is

 18445431375

because

 this is related to Sporadic Groups. Take the prime factorization of the orders of sporadic groups, then "increase" them to the next prime numbers, e.g. 2^4 × 3^2 × 5 × 11 turns into 3^4 × 5^2 × 7 × 13 (the first term in the sequence)

making the missing term in the sequence

 The Tits Group, which is sometimes considered a sporadic group.

